# first jquery event is happening, but not the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to do a pagination on my webpage, problem is I messed up something and something is not working when clicking on a pagination anchor the second time.

here is my code

```
$('.pagination a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($('.pagination a:first').text()=='1');
    if($('.pagination a:first').text()=='1'){
        if($('.pagination a').index(this)!=0){
            var index_a_cambiar = $('.pagination a').index(this);
            $('tbody').html('');
            $('.pagination').html('');
            $('.pagination').html('<a href="#"><</a>');
            for ( var j = 0; j < cant_pag; j++ ) {                  
                var textact1 = $('tbody').html();
                $('tbody').html(textact1+'<tr>'+arreglo_td[index_a_cambiar][j]+'</tr>');
                var textact2 = $('.pagination').html();
                if(j==index_a_cambiar){
                    $('.pagination').html(textact2 + '<a href="#" id="activo">'+(j+1)+'</a>');
                }else{
                    $('.pagination').html(textact2 + '<a href="#">'+(j+1)+'</a>');
                }
            }
            var textact3 = $('.pagination').html();
            $('.pagination').html(textact3+'<a href="#">></a>');
        }
    } else{
    }
});
```

I know I have nothing on my else, but I can see that this script is not running because the preventDefault method is not working, and I dont get the first alert.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are replacing `pagination` elements content, so event bound to `a` no longer exists. You can use event delagation to resolve this by binding the event to its container that exists in DOM at any point in time (i.e `.pagination` if that is the one that is available any time you need the event).

```
$('.pagination').on('click', 'a', function(event){
.....
....
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You know what sometimes the `title` of the question gives some clues  :)

Comment: @PSL :D I know, but I'm still at my first coffee gulp :)

Comment: question.. is it always better to use .on instead of .click?

Comment: @PabloPerez Yes it is just a wrapper to bind any event, plus you get the advantage of using the event delegation syntax provided by `.on` as in this example (Provided your version of jquery supports it)... See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)